# Applying Meteor collection insert in javascript array for loop

Tags: meteor

I am new to javascript and very new to Meteor. Is this code correct? I need to define a function which will take an array of values and insert them in a Meteor Collection "FooterButtons"?

Client code

```
replaceCollectionContents(['NO', 'B', 'YES']);
```

Both code

```
replaceCollectionContents = function (buttonsList) {
  FooterButtons.remove();
  for(i = 0; i < buttonsList.length; i++) {
    FooterButtons.insert(buttonsList[i]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Care to leave a comment as to what improvement you could have done to write this question so that other may learn how to avoid writing a question which attached down-voting? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. What specifically have you tried, what specific error are you seeing, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly insert a string to a collection. The insert method expects a document which is of type object.

Try this instead -

```js
FooterButtons.insert({ text: buttonsList[i] });
```

Also, I notice that you are trying to clear your FooterButtons collection. Please note that you cannot clear a collection like this from the client side as it is considered untrusted code. From client side, you can only remove one document at a time, specified by its _id.

I would recommend you to use a method instead.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  replaceCollectionContents: function (buttonsList) {
    // remove all existing documents in the collection
    FooterButtons.remove({});

    // insert new button documents into the collection
    buttonsList.forEach(function (button) {
      FooterButtons.insert({ text: button });
    });
  }
});
```

And call this method when needed

```js
Meteor.call("replaceCollectionContents", ['NO', 'B', 'YES']);
```

Inside the method, note that I'm passing a `{}` selector to the `remove` method because for safety reasons, Meteor does not remove any documents if selector is omitted.

You can read more about [remove](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/remove) in Meteor docs.

Comment: I get an error "this version of javascript is not supported", my Meteor installation has ecmascript@0.1.6 and ecmascript-runtime@0.2.6. is your code written in ECMAScript 6?

Comment: Yes, I have used some ES6 for method declaration. I have edited the answer. This should prevent the error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to seed data into `FooterButtons` collection, correct?

Put this code somewhere on your `server` folder:

```
buttonsList = ['NO', 'B', 'YES'];

if (FooterButtons.find().count() === 0) {
  _.each(buttonsList, function(button) {
    FooterButtons.insert({text: button});
  });
}
```

Run meteor and check your mongodb FooterButtons collection. Let me know. I'll make explanation if this work

If you need to update, then update it:

```
FooterButtons.update({text:'B'}, {$set:{text:'Extra'}});
```

Comment: Yes it does. But if I change the text of one of the items in the array (say B to Extra), the template does not show the new text